# Is there a way to test System/exit in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have code that runs `(System/exit 0)` and I want to test that portion of the code. I tried testing it with `with-redefs` but I found out I'm not allowed to do that for Java methods. How can I go about testing this?

Comment: I would argue that you should rather try to avoid calling System/exit outside of your main function (assuming that this is code that you can actually change) - for individual components of your program to exit the program itself is a violation of the separation of concerns, which is also why it's hard to test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot directly mock that function, though like all good CS problems* you can solve it by adding one extra level of indirection:

```
(defn exit-now! [] 
   (System/exit 0))
```

then in your tests you can with-redef out the call to the clojure function exit-now.

```
(with-redefs [exit-now! (constantly "we exit here")]
    (is (= "we exit here" (code that calls exit))))
```

and perhaps you could nudge the developers of that function away from the practice of calling System/exit from deep within a project.

*except performance problems of course.

Answer (score 7):

If you really need to test calls to `System/exit`, you can use a [`SecurityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) to disallow them and then catch the resulting `SecurityException`s:

```
(System/setSecurityManager
  (proxy [SecurityManager] []
    (checkExit [status]
      (throw (SecurityException.
               (str "attempted to exit with status " status))))
    (checkCreateClassLoader []
      true)
    (checkPermission [_]
      true)))

(System/exit 5)
;> SecurityException attempted to exit with status 5  user/eval6/fn--11 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:2)

(try (System/exit 5) (catch SecurityException e :foo))
;= :foo
```

In general, though, wrapping the method call in a function like Arthur suggested tends to be the saner approach.